# Sikuli on Ubuntu : cannot load such file -- sikuli (Load Error)

Tags: ruby, sikuli

Sikuli on Ubuntu : cannot load such file -- sikuli (Load Error)

> Error message is :
>   /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
>   require': cannot load such file -- sikuli (LoadError) from
>   /home/ashrivas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:inrequire'

Ruby version is 2.0.0p247 Sikuli version is 0.3.0

I do not see the Sikuli when I do gem list also. But when I install, it says successfully installed.

Comment: You will probably get faster response on the sikuli forum - https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli

Comment: Do you use bundler?  Check that you install sikuli under the same rvm that you use for running your script.  Does it help?